# setInterval() is not firing after casper.run()

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, setinterval, casperjs

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('http://google.com/', function () {

  console.log('URL loaded.');

});

// It does work if I comment the line below.
casper.run();

setInterval(function () {

  console.log('setInterval log.');

}, 2000);
```

How can I make the *setInterval()* method to work with the *casper.run()* method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass your `setInterval` as a lambda function:

```
casper.run(function() {
    setInterval(function () {
        console.log('setInterval log.');
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: But if i want to run the setting from casperjs , use    setInterval(function () {
        casper.run(function () {
            // this.echo('Done').exit();
            this.echo('Done');      
        });
    }, 2000); is more correct ?